# Print missing characters in Chinese writin

Tags: xetex, symbols, chinese

I am trying to write in Chinese this character 爫 using latex.
But I only get a square

I am sure the character is on the font, as I have used it in excel for example.

This is my code:

```
%!TeX program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{清松手寫體1}

\begin{document}

    爫


\end{document}
```

I am using TEXstudio
And XeLaTex to compile.

Thanks

Comment: quite probably it is not in the font and excel is using some fallback font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

How attached are you to the xeCJK machinery and the Qingsong Handwriting font package? If your answer is "I'm not closely attached", you could consider loading the `fontspec` package along with a suitable Opentype font. For instance, both `Noto Serif SC` and `Noto Serif TC` feature the needed glyph.

Incidentally, `fontspec` is usable by both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
%!TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif SC} % https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+SC
   % or should it be 'Noto Serif TC'?
\begin{document}
    爫
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solved the problem.

Comment: @ManuTen - Thanks. If you feel that your typeseting problem has been fully solved by my answer, feel free to click on the "accept" check-mark symbol. ;-)

Comment: Hi, it was working, but then I began to game this error:
Undefined control sequence. \setmainfont
Missing \begin{document}. \setmainfont{N
I am using the same program above.
It compiles and makes a pdf with the name of the font.

Comment: @ManuTen - If `\setmainfont` is throwing an "Undefined control sequence" error, your document isn't loading the `fontspec` package. (This package defines the `\setmainfont` macro.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that’s what I thought, so I uninstalled and reinstalled miktex and texstudio, but it keeps me the same error. Any ideas? kind regard

Comment: @ManuTen - I'm afraid the answer is "no". Sorry.

Comment: I solved it, I unistalled mixtex and deleted its c drive files and reinstalled